# How to group by two columns and get a sum down a third column

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe where each row is a prescription event and contains a drug name, a postcode, and the quantity prescribed. I need to find the total quantity of every drug prescribed in every postcode.

I need to group by postcode, then by drug name, and find the sum of the cells in the "items" column for every group.

This is my function that I want to apply to every postcode group:

```
def count(group):
    sums = []
    for bnf_name in group['bnf_name']:
        sum_ = group[group['bnf_name'] == bnf_name]['items'].sum()
        sums.append(sum_)
    group['sum'] = sums

merged.groupby('post_code').apply(count).head()
merged.head()
```

Calling merged.head() returns the original merged dataframe without a new column for sums like I would expect. I think there is something I don't get about the apply() function on a groupby object...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to define your own function

```
merged.groupby(['post_code','bnf_name'])['items'].sum()
```